# Oracle equivalent of ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST query hints

Tags: sql, oracle, locking

In SQL Server I used the following hints inside queries:

- rowlock (row level locking)
- updlock (prevents dirty reads)
- readpast (don't block waiting for a rowlock, go to the first unlocked row)

e.g.

```
select top 1 data from tablez with (rowlock,updlock,readpast);
```

Are there equivalent in-query hints for Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent of `ROWLOCK` is the `FOR UPDATE` clause

```
select *
from emp
for update;
```

Since 11g Oracle has documented the `SKIP LOCKED` syntax which is the equivalent of `READPAST`:

```
select *
from emp
for update skip locked;
```

This syntax has worked for ages (it is fundamental to Advanced Queuing) but if it's not in the docs it's not supported,

There is no equivalent of `UPDLOCK` lock because Oracle flat out doesn't allow dirty reads. Find out more.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you sure about your last statement? It seems like FOR UPDATE is a replacement for UPDLOCK, whereas ROWLOCK is more about the granularity of the lock employed.

Comment: There's no simple one-to-one relationship between the lock types. DML in Oracle is driven by row-level locks. There's no concept of shared read locks in Oracle as it uses a different consistency mechanism. Exclusive insert/update/delete locks are held on the data record itself. Oracle only uses table level locks to prevent concurrent DDL.