# Select top N with "for update skip locked" in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, top-n

In Oracle, I can select the top 1 message in a sorted table with

```
select messageid from(
    select 
        messageid, 
        RANK() over (order by messageid asc) as msg_rank 
    from messages
) where msg_rank=1;
```

And as I discovered in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938677/oracle-equivalent-of-rowlock-updlock-readpast-query-hints) I can select a row exclusively with

```
select * from messages where rownum < 2 for update skip locked;
```

However I can't merge these two concepts together

```
select messageid from(
    select 
        messageid, 
        RANK() over (order by messageid asc) as msg_rank 
    from messages
) where msg_rank=1 for update skip locked;

-- results in error
-- ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

How can I select the top N with readpast locking?

Comment: I think this blog post has some relevant thoughts: http://markjbobak.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/unintended-consequences/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work?

```
select messageid from messages 
    where messageid in (
       select messageid from(
         select 
          messageid, 
          RANK() over (order by messageid asc) as msg_rank 
          from messages
       ) where msg_rank=1
    )
  for update skip locked;
```

Comment: If it's done in two steps, aren't I introducing a potential race condition? I follow your logic, but I find it hard to believe that Oracle can't do what SQL Server can.

Comment: That query executed fine. I'll go on to test that the locking is working as intended, but it seems good to go. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the semantics of skip locked are probably a bit tricky in this case, even on SQL Server. I would expect the query above to first find the top N messages, and then skip amongst them (so that you could end up with less than N records). And I do not think that there is a way around that in general (short of locking the whole table).

Comment: So you actually select top n <= N rows here.