# What would the Oracle SQL version of this T-SQL be?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I'm trying to port some SQL Server code over to using Oracle, and I'm uncertain about one particular sql statement.  I don't have a good understanding of the locking in Oracle the way I understand the SQL Server locking.

```
WITH message AS (
  SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [MyTable]
  WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK)
  ORDER BY [RowVersion] ASC)
DELETE FROM message 
OUTPUT deleted.Id, deleted.CorrelationId, deleted.ReplyToAddress, 
       deleted.Recoverable, deleted.Expires, deleted.Headers,
       deleted.Body;
```

Comment: It depends. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Here seems to be similar question and there's an answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938677/oracle-equivalent-of-rowlock-updlock-readpast-query-hints